# gpars to create parallel jobs in pipeline plugin for jenkins

Tags: multithreading, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, gpars

My environment is Tibco, where I have 200 to 300 services. My design needs to trigger the 'stop' command to all these services parallely. Please provide some insight as to how I deal(code) the threading mechanism within Gpars. Examples will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
GParsPool.withPool(PreVerifyManager.THREADS){
                servicePathList.eachParallel{
                    InitiateApplicationDowntime(it)
                }
            }
```

I was totally a new bee with groovy, after 2 months of learning, researching and working, this just fit my requirement